# Реализация игры "Морской бой" на wpf (с использованием MVVM, или MVC, или др.)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Привет всем! Разделил по слоям: **Model** - классы "игрок", "поле", и наверное "игровой процесс".
**View** - непосредственно само окно.
А вот по поводу посредника, ясно, что он будет обрабатывать действие на dataGridView и в соответствии с этим изменять объект и отображать в окне изменения в этом объекте.
*Вопрос в том, как вообще реализовать эту логику и какой паттерн или "технику" выбрать для этой реализации?*
Заранее спасибо)

Comment: MVVM да, а вот DataGridView не предназначен для этого, он для отображения таблиц, а у вас квадратная матрица, это разные вещи, хоть и выглядят похоже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Вероятно понадобится не dataGridView, а UniformGrid эта панель дает одинаковые по размеру клетки, хотя можно обойтись и обычным гридом.

2) Работу с клетками (их состоянием, внешний вид) нужно будет организовать через кастомные DataTemplate.

3) В качестве посредника - класс ViewModel, который для вашей View будет DataContext.

Что еще, сказать? Тут не на одну страницу ответ будет.